# Client supplied XML issues with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml

I'm looking to do a project using PHP and SimpleXML. I want to have a client app to send a XML message to a web server and then have the PHP script parse out the values that are needed with SimpleXML. In general, from a security standpoint, I would always do validation against any client input because it can never be trusted.

Are there any security solutions that I need to incorporate into my design? Does SimpleXML at least validate the XML structure and handle error gracefully? I'm assuming I would have to validate the values in the elements themselves such that the value in count below is really indeed an integer and not something crazy.

```
<root>
    <count>1</count>
</root>
```

Comment: What security issues are you expecting to guard against? Something inherent to XML parsing? If you're just worried about the sanity of the input, the fact that it's wrapped in XML is irrelevant - what you are validating is the *content*, not its *transmission format*.

Comment: `Does SimpleXML at least validate the XML structure and handle error gracefully?` yes, [see here](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php). Other than that, what you need to validate really depends on your application and what it needs the incoming data to be

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML will throw an exception if the XML is invalid

```
$xml = '<root><element>bad</element></root';
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

Outputs

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : expected '&gt;' in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;root&gt;&lt;element&gt;bad&lt;/element&gt;&lt;/root in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                   ^ in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in [...][...]:2
Stack trace:
#0 [...][...](2): SimpleXMLElement-&gt;__construct('&lt;root&gt;&lt;element&gt;...')
#1 {main}

thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```